# Facade does not implement getFacadeAccessor when running composer update in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, docker, composer-php

For my development environment, I am running Laravel, SQL and NGINX all in 3 separate docker containers. I am attempting to update composer with `composer update` which has worked perfectly in all my previous projects.

However, it is now giving the below error:

> Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-intl * but it is missing
> from your system

After lots of searching around, I tried this:

```
composer update ignore-platform-reqs
```

It then got all the way through perfectly fine, but once it finished it seemed to automatically run these to lines afterwards:

`> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump` and `> @php artisan package:discover --ansi`

A error is then thrown:

> Facade does not implement getFacadeAccessor method.

Followed by.

> Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the
> post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

I previously had permission denied issues when running anything to do with the composer, so I deleted my vendor folder and that seemed to fix the composer install. I am running on Windows 10.

Comment: why not install the required php extension?

Comment: I forgot to mention why, my apologies. The tutorials I could find for installing those extensions were all for Ubuntu. In addition to this, I tried installing composer with their Windows installer but when it asks me to select a PHP cli the options are blank, where as on all the tutorials it shows multiple options.

Comment: ok. not sure how dire the solution to this is, but i'm pretty sure php artisan package:discover just shows you the "latest and greatest" package updates available so it's not really needed in your composer.json file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. When I run that command, I once again get the `Facade does not implement getFacadeAccessor method.` error.

Comment: I tried running that in the php docker container and in my terminal which is sitting inside the project directory. It seems when I run any php command in my project directory terminal I get the above error.

Comment: Do you have any custom Facades?

Comment: I have none. The project has just been set up and I have not touched any of the code. I follow this guide for each project and it always works: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose. 

However when I get to the `docker-compose exec app php artisan key:generate` command on Step 8 I also get the error. It happens when I run anything with php.